# How is the implicit flow of Opend ID Connect secure?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, access-token, openid-connect

I understand that the in case of Single page applications that rely on bunch of rest apis, the implicit flow of Open Id Connect is recommended. What i fail to understand is how is it secure? The Authorization server returns the access and id token in the URL fragment after the user is successfully logged in. Shouldn't the access tokenbe handled with more care? And doesn't this give 'access' to the access token to potentially anyone. I might be missing some basic details here but this to me looks like a shortcoming. I understand that we can make the access token short lived but it still does not make the implicit flow any less secure.
On the other hand, the code flow seems much more secure in comparison. Only the code is visible in the browser and that does not make any sense unless you have the client id and client secret of the application.
We currently want to implement the implict flow in our SPA and i assume this questions is bound to come from other team members. Let me know if the question is not clear to anyone.

Comment: So what is your concern? Is it that the token is sent in the url fragment and not in say the request body?

Comment: If the token is visible in the browser is it not a security concern? It can be sniffed by other users as well. Is my understanding correct? Can secure cookies be better alternative to this?

Comment: By what users? Do you mean somebody standing behind you and looking at your monitor? Yes, they can probably see it. :) But even if it was in a cookie or response header/body or anything else, a user having access to the client would still have access. So I'm trying to understand what the threat is that you have in mind.

Comment: Yes any other user having access to the client's browser. Or may be a malicious javascript that can sniff access tokens as well.

Comment: But that is not different from any other method. XSS can indeed steal the token.

Comment: What I have read during my search is that XSS attacks can be prevented by the means of https only cookies. I am definitely not an expert on web security thats why these basic questions are developing in my mind.